# Is it possible to set up a pptp server in windows via console?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, pptp

I want to be able to turn a machine into a pptp server from commandline so that it can be scripted, is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to script it? Wouldnt you just set it up once?

Comment: yeah, it will be for distributing to techs at multiple locations